# Positioning of tables and cells in Firefox is off

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position, html-table

I'm working on this website, and I have 5 horizontal table cells. In the middle section I want to place my content. Whenever I place it, it shows up correct in Chrome and IE, but underneath it in Firefox. I know this is a common problem for Firefox, but the solution mentioned are not working in this case.

This is my website ; http://luukvanaggelen.com/test/

This is the middle div

```
#midden{
    background-color:#30F;
    height:100%;
    min-width:424px;
    width:425px;
    position:relative;
}
```

These are its direct children.

```
.pivothome, .pivot2 , .pivot3{
    width:9px;
    height: 9px;
    position:absolute;
    color:#000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here, or create a jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment MelanciaUK. I tried creating a jsFiddle but it would not work without the images etc etc. Maybe if you look at the source code of the website I posted? Thanks!

Comment: 1) .container{top:0;} 2) use % width for divs with display:table-cell;